# ¿Cómo mostrar un modal en net core?

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net

espero me puedan apoyar comunidad, Estoy realizando una aplicación donde al dar de baja un empleado, quiero que salga un modal con un `textarea` para enviar comentarios de MotivBaja, pero el detalle es que cuando mando a llamar mi método, se salta el modal y no puedo escribir, alguien sabe como podria hacer detener mi método hasta que llene el textarea?

Este es mi método:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BorrarEmpleado(int idEmpleado, string motivoBaja)
    {
        var idUsuario = servicioUsuario.ObtenerIdUsuario();
        var empleado = await repositorioEmpleado.ObtenerEmpleadoPorId(idUsuario, idEmpleado);

        if(empleado is null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NoEncontrado", "Home");
        }

        await repositorioEmpleado.Borrar(idEmpleado, empleado.NoEmpleado, motivoBaja);

        TempData["mensaje"] = "El empleado se borro correctamente";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
<form asp-action="BorrarEmpleado" class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-light">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdEmpleado" />

            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col">
                    <label asp-for="MotivoBaja" class="form-label"></label>
                    <textarea asp-for="MotivoBaja" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="MotivoBaja" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 gap-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Borrar</button>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg px-4" asp-action="Index">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Este es mi modal que quiero mostrar:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero comento, si veo que lo muestra pero inmediatamente me redirecciona a mi index, como puedo detener mi método para que pueda ingresar el textarea que quiero colocar en el modal para enviar dicha información.

Comment: Ya lo intentaste por javascript o hay alguna razón para no usar javscript?

Comment: puedes quitar asp-action="BorrarEmpleado" y hacerlo por medio de ajax lo que hace cada boton. y en vez de IActionResult pondria JsonResult

Comment: Por solo queria saber si hay alguna manera de hacerlo con net core, solo eso!

Comment: Lo mejor es que lo utilices por medio de Javascript, realmente no he visto que se controle esto mediante el servidor.